# Dynamic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How would one define the return type of the `fn` function below?

```js
const fn = (propName1: string, propName2: string) => {
  return { 
   [propName1]: () => true 
   [propName2]: () => 'abc'
  }
}
const x = fn('customProp1', 'customProp2')
console.log(x.customProp1)
console.log(x.customProp2)
```

e.g.

```js
type FN = (propName: string)=> {
  [propName1]: ()=>true
  [propName2]: ()=>string
}
```

This is for two custom methods, but ideally the solution should allow for any number of custom methods and properties.

Comment: Unless you're going to make the function generic, it would be something like `{[k: string]: () => true}`. There is no dynamic typing going on; even if you use a generic type parameter, Typescript is a statically typed language and the types don't even exist at runtime.

Comment: There's no specific type that corresponds to that; you could make the function generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8KppW); does that meet your needs?

Comment: @kaya3: good point - this is dynamic typing and likely typescript won't allow it!

Comment: @jcalz - nice!  That is a solution if one is defining only one property - per my original question, but how could one do this for two custom properties?

Comment: @TrevTheDev It's hard to know what you're asking about without a [mre]; maybe you want [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlxP5N) or maybe something else?  In any case I'm happy to write any of this up as an answer as long as it's in the question itself (so if you want answers about two custom properties, please [edit] the question to ask about them).  Let me know what you want to see here.

Comment: @jcalz : thank you, your second solution did the trick!  Fortunately I'm only dealing with 2 custom properties as per your example, however if one was dealing with many, your solution would also work, but would also mean messy complex code!

Comment: @jcalz: [Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20220104#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwEIFcCWAbAJhATgHgAVcB7MARiggA9gIA7LAZyieFzXoHMAaKYsgCYqtBs1btOXAHxQAvFADeAKChQA2oSid+pClAA+uoQF0AXPxF1GLAWGFQA-FAAUASjnS4JEhggBDeigLd082Dm5lAF9lZQAzFHoAY2A0EiCSRAgU1EwcAjtKGmtxcKk+O2FisRYy7mkXVSgwPXILOt4mlqF2yW4eZTdg2ERc7DwiVoq9QVkVNVwIYBRcIPm1DW6Kc1chzyh2FAgBjc2Znfd5WS3BE6goqH8WeGR0cYKp43tpaNik9LYj3kUEyCGywDG+XwAHIKNC+LDBNCGrDyPCoIjoW5lP96ExfBAAHQYEhcFz+QkUdzY3H4vzE0nkymCalAA) is my working solution based on you code.  Thanks again!

Comment: @TrevTheDev, please [edit] your question to ask exactly the question you mean to ask, and then I'd be happy to write up an answer.  Are you asking for one prop name?  Two?  An arbitrary number?  The comments here are just to understand the scope of the question, and should not serve as a substitute for a posted answer (a mod might well come by and delete these, and future readers shouldn't have to read through comments to understand what's going on.)  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @jcalz - thanks, I've edited the question to ask for two or more custom properties.

Comment: "two or more custom properties" I only see the question asking about "two"... if you want "or more" then you should specify that (is it supposed to be [variadic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found so far is as follows:

```js
type Fn<P1 extends string, P2 extends string>={ [K in P1]: 'whatever1' } & { [K in P2]: 'whatever2' }

type Solution1 = Fn<'customProp1','customProp2'> 
// { customProp1: "whatever1"; } & { customProp2: "whatever2"; }

type Identity<T> = T extends object ? {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } : T

type Solution2 = Identity<Fn<'customProp1','customProp2'>> 
// { customProp1: "whatever1"; customProp2: "whatever2";}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `propName` is a `string`, you can do:

```js
type FN_return = {[propName: string]: ()=>true};
```

Comment: Be aware that the `propName` in the type declaration is totally unrelated to the function parameter named `propName`; the type does not specify that the object has one key or that that key is the same as the function's parameter.

Comment: yes, I get that. I was using `propName` because then all of the references are the same and it is easier to follow. any other identifier would have worked. (k, key, ...)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This wont work if one has two properties being defined: e.g. propName1 and propName2 - as typescript doesn't allow more than one of those types.  Further any derived object, will need to have it's type explicitly redefined - which is not ideal as `x.customProp` could be undefined.

Comment: What do you mean? the `[key: keyType]` syntax works for any number of properties. it allows you to have keys that you don't have to define upfront.

Comment: as for the second statement about derived objects, that is true. the `[key: keyType]` syntax doesn't specify what properties need to be on the object, just the type of the keys and values of any additional properties.

Comment: @2pichar - the following is not allowed ```
type FN_return = {
  [propName1: string]: ()=>true;
  [propName2: string]: ()=>true;
}
```

Comment: see [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be safe and are ok with being a little verbose, then use TypeScript Generics:

```
const fn = <T extends string>(propName: T): { [_ in T]: () => true } => {
  return { [propName]: () => true } as any; // a cast is sadly required for generic return types
}
const x = fn('customProp')
console.log(x.customProp) // ✅ works fine
x.notHere // ❌ compile error
```

Also, this will automatically support if you are passing in a generic `string` type with the unsafe counterpart that the other answer used.

```
const y = fn("foo" as string); // same as Record<string, () => true>
y.foo; // compiles but is valid
y.asdf; // compiles but is undefined
```

If you wanted to be extremely safe, then you could actually change your return type when someone passes in a `string` (not exact string type) using conditional types to show it could be `undefined`:

```
const fn = <T extends string>(propName: T): { [_ in T]: Exclude<undefined | (() => true), string extends T ? never : undefined> } => {
  return { [propName]: () => true } as any;
}
const x = fn("hello"); // { hello: () => true; }
x.asdf // ❌ compile error
const y = fn("hello" as string); // { [x: string]: (() => true) | undefined; }
y.foo // (() => true) | undefined
y.hello // (() => true) | undefined
```